# Sqlite query on Dates

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am currently using sqlite for my windows 8 app . I want a query that will give me data between the date user first enter the data and today . I am not sure how to do that :( . My Baby Sleep structure is something

```
public TimeSpan sleepTime { get; set; }
    public string babyName { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan totalSleepTime { get; set; }
    public string today {get; set;}
    public string State { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan awakeTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan totalAwakeTime {get; set;}
```

(today is in string because i m not sure how to handle that if it is DateTime)

I have tried storing date as string like this

```
await Conn.QueryAsync<BabySleep>("SELECT * FROM BabySleep WHERE today BETWEEN ? AND ?", FirstSleepDate, DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("d"));
```

But it didn't work.

2ndly i want to calculate avg on daily basis. e.g, i need to calculate daily avg sleep time. How can i do that .

regards.

Comment: Remember we're not mind readers.  If you want a good answer you need to post more information.  For example, post the table structure of that `BabySleep`

Comment: And further reference you need to store the date in a specific format -- see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html  (under time strings)